# How can I create custom entity "groups" in CRM 4?

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-4

I'm looking to mimic the behavior of the "activitypointer" entity with custom entities.

For example, I'd like to have "equipmentpointer" that will provide a rollup view of all types of equipment associated with an account.  Is this possible to create programatically?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short: isn't.

Comment: I kinda figured as much. I may use an iFrame in the account form and pull my equipment hierarchy into that.